# gem install not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I recently installed rubygems 1.3.7. When I try to install rails by typing :gem install rails I get an error like this:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
no such file to load -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

Comment: Could you give more details like your operating system and version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem while installing sqlite3 .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122254/problem-while-installing-sqlite3)

Comment: please don't ask the same question a lot of time. Edit your first maybe.

Comment: @Shingara ruby 1.8.7 and rubygems 1.3.7 and OS suggest me what to do next

Comment: @Shingara actually I am new to rais just started exploring it today I am following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Ruby install is missing the zlib extension.
If you installed Ruby from source, make sure that you have the appropriate development headers (in Fedora - zlib-devel, in Ubuntu - libzlib-dev or something like this).
You can check if it's installed by running the following command:

```
ruby -rzlib -e 'puts Zlib::VERSION'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
rvm remove ruby-x.x.x
```

then

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

then

```
rmv install 1.9.X
```

If the problem persists, verify that you indeed indeed all the requirement libraries, or run:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential libssl-dev libreadline5 libreadline5-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

Note: you may have to uninstall and reinstall everything again.